# How to fix the following logcat error message in android studio running on linux

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Whenever i try and run any of my applications via an emulator on android studio i get the following error message in the logcat.

```
Emulator: Warning: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR points to non- 
existing path '/run/user/1000/snap.android-studio', please create it 
with 0700 permissions. ((null):0, (null))
```

I should mention that at times my applications run perfectly okay but that at other times they do not and i also get he following error message

```
Emulator: pc_memory_init: above 4g size: 40000000
```

Comment: From your 1st log message, I can say that, it is not an error first of all, it is trying to tell you that the path set for environment variable XDG_RUNTIME_DIR does not exits, or if exits then it does not have sufficient permission (requires 0700). For 2nd log (not sure, guessing from question), it could be due to limitation of memory, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size solution, might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for that im still very a much a beginner at all of this

Comment: On linux? have you tried "sudo mkdir -m 700 /run/user/1000/snap.android-studio"

Comment: it seem you install android studio with snap it's better to remove that and install it without out snap

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -m 0700 /run/user/1000/snap.android-studio
```