# Emulator: statvfs('/home/zf/...snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed: No such file or directory

Tags: android-studio, emulation

I used Ubuntu 18.04, my Android Studio is 3.4, when I run app on a real phone, it is OK, when I used a virtual device, the error report was:

```
2:45    Emulator: statvfs('/home/zf/.android/avd/Pixel_3_API_22.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed: No such file or directory
2:45    Gradle build finished in 6 s 850 ms
2:46    ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed
2:46    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
3:17    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

It seems that, the key reason is "No such file or directory", what does that mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the error like

> (Emulator: statvfs('/home/zf/.android/avd/Pixel_3_API_22.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed:
>   No such file or directory)

by changing the group owner of `ram.img` to `libvirt`:

```
sudo chgrp libvirt ram.img
```

And changing the permissions to allow both read and write:

```
chmod 766 ram.img
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually goes together with this error:

> ```
>     Emulator: Warning: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR points to non- 
> existing path '/run/user/1000/snap.android-studio', please create it 
> with 0700 permissions. ((null):0, (null))
> ```

Which in my case got fixed with this:

```
mkdir -m 0700 /run/user/1000/snap.android-studio
```

See [How to fix the following logcat error message in android studio running on linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140147/how-to-fix-the-following-logcat-error-message-in-android-studio-running-on-linux/1171054#1171054)

Comment: Did this, the other error did go, but not the one from this question.

Comment: The fact that you have to use custom solutions on linux to use software like Android studio sucks. I would just try to create the file and see what happens. Something like "touch ../../ram.img and chown it to my user.